# How to remove Borders From Buttons IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using Material Theme in IntelliJ but there are borders around search box and buttons, I want to remove them.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUsLW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gskf8.png)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be something that is tuned within the Material theme plugin, not IntelliJ IDEA. Please see if [this article](https://material-theme.com/docs/configuration/accents/) helps.